# Expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c, arrays

When I try to build this code, it gives me the errors "Expression must have pointer-to-object type on line 43 and 51 on the i in sum[i] along with the error "subscript requires array or pointer type" in line 51 again on the sum[i]. How would I be able to fix this so I can build this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 5

int main()
{
   int i;
   int sum;
   int c[SIZE] = { 29, 28, 25, 9, 4 };
   int d[SIZE] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
   {
      printf("Enter c[%d] \n", i);
      scanf_s("%d", &c[i]);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      printf("c[%d] = %d and d[%d] = %d\n", i, c[i], i, d[i]);
   }

   sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      sum[i] = d[i] + c[i];
   }

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
      printf ("sum[%d] = %d \n", i, sum[i]);
   }

   return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I be able to fix this so I can build this code?

Make `sum` an array too.

```
int sum[SIZE];
```

Also, fix the `return` statement. Make it return an `int`.

```
return 0;
```

You may omit the `return` statement altogether also.